# No module named 'featuretools.features' error pip install in Jupyter notebook

Tags: featuretools

When I try to install anything from featuretools.features using pip in a Jupyter notebook, I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'featuretools.features'

Everything else I'm importing from featuretools is working, so I'm not sure why this is the case. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: featuretools.features isn't a module that is in the most recent version of featuretools, so this error is expected. where are you seeing an example of code that imports it?

Comment: @MaxKanter I was looking at this documentation from a previous version https://docs.featuretools.com/feature_engineering/manual_feature_engineering.html. 

Has all of that functionality since been replaced by feature primitives?
https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/primitives.html?highlight=transform%20features#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the equivalent documentation for the newest Featuretools version.
https://docs.featuretools.com/feature_engineering_language/feature-types.html?highlight=day%20window

Here's the module I was looking for:

> import featuretools.primitives